# How do I specify in a Makefile.am script that I only want to compile object .o files?

Tags: makefile, automake, gnu-make

I have a `Makefile.am` which will be responsible for building a final application binary:

```
project/src/Makefile.am
```

Also in the src directory is a sub-directory called `ctrnn` which contains an additional `Makefile.am`:

```
project/src/ctrnn/Makefile.am
```

Now, `ctrnn/Makefile.am` should only generate object `.o` files with the idea being that the top-level `Makefile.am` should use the object files generated in subdirectory `ctrnn` to build the binary.

This is the `ctrnn/Makefile.am`:

```
SOURCES = network.cpp\
    neuron.cpp

AM_CPPFLAGS=  @CXXFLAGS@
```

Based on this `Makefile.am` file, I want to end up with network.o and neuron.o. I am generating the according `Makefile` using Automake etc, yet when I try and then execute the make file, it doesn't do anything and just says:

```
make: Nothing to be done for `all'
```

I know why this is, I need to specify the build target. But how do I do this in the `ctrnn/Makefile.am` script given that I don't want to build a binary which would require `bin_PROGRAMS` but actual object files `network.o` and `neuron.o`?

(Note if I do specify a bin_PROGRAMS name, it rightly ends up complaining of an undefined reference to main).

What am I do wrong?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Automake cannot build objects without an explicit target (program, library) that will use these objects.  One reason is that compilation options are specified per-target.  If two targets, e.g. two binaries use the same object but have different compilation option, the same object may have to be compiled twice.

You have three ways to do what you want, they all involve tying your source files to some target.

1. Do not use a `src/ctrnn/Makefile.am`, just make reference to the subdirectory source files from your `src/Makefile.am`:

   ```
   bin_PROGRAMS = foo
   foo_SOURCES = main.c crtnn/network.cpp crtnn/neuron.cpp
   ```

   Note that this will build `network.o` and `neuron.o` in the same directory as `main.o`.  If you want objects in subdirectories, use `AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = subdir-objects`.
2. Use a convenience library.  In `src/crtnn/Makefile.am` make a library of your two objects:

   ```
   noinst_LIBRARIES = libcrtnn.a
   libcrtnn_a_SOURCES = network.cpp neuron.cpp
   ```

   and in `src/Makefile.am`, link your executable to the library:

   ```
   bin_PROGRAMS = foo
   foo_SOURCES = main.c
   foo_LDADD = crtnn/libcrtnn.a
   SUBDIRS = crtnn
   ```

   It's called "convenience" when it is not going to be installed (you can tell because of the `noinst_` prefix): it is just used during the build.  And this is a static library, so the result is the same as if you had replaced `crtnn/libcrtnn.a` by `crtnn/network.o` and `crtn/neuro.o` when linking `foo`.
3. Use a Libtool convenience library.  This requires more setup if you are not using Libtool already.  You should add a call `LT_INIT` in `configure.ac` and rerun `autoreconf` to install the libtool files.  Then you can update `src/crtnn/Makefile.am` to make a library of your two objects as follows:

   ```
   noinst_LTLIBRARIES = libcrtnn.la
   libcrtnn_la_SOURCES = network.cpp neuron.cpp
   ```

   and `src/Makefile.am` as follows:

   ```
   bin_PROGRAMS = foo
   foo_SOURCES = main.c
   foo_LDADD = crtnn/libcrtnn.la
   SUBDIRS = crtnn
   ```

   What is the difference? you may ask, almost none.  One advantage of using Libtool convenience libraries is that they can be nested: a Libtool library can include another Libtool library (this is convenient when you have a deep hierarchy of source code and you are building a library at each level).  Also Libtool convenience libraries can be used to build a shared library if you want.  Automake's static libraries cannot.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using the libtool method, works perfectly :-)

Comment: Thanks for a helping hand for me striving in the autotools/libtool hell. And do us all a favor: live long and prosper !

Comment: foo_LDADD?

Isn't that supposed to be 

    foo_LIBADD

Comment: @EgbertS `_LIBADD` is used to add objects to a library, but `foo` not a library.

Comment: Superb comprehensive answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could simply specify source files in project/src/Makefile.am and not have a Makefile.am in ctrnn:

```
maude_SOURCES = ctrnn/network.cpp ctrnn/neuron.cpp
```

or you can use a libtool convenience library.  In ctrnn/Makefile.am, put:

```
noinst_LTLIBRARIES = libctrnn.la
libctrnn_la_SOURCES = network.cpp neuron.cpp
```

and in src/Makefile.am, put

```
LDADD = ctrnn/libmylib.la
```

If you aren't already using libtool, you'll also need to add LT_INIT to configure.ac.

Answer (score 0):

Better yet, you could FORCE a make using a source-less target by doing this:

```
SUBDIRS = sub1 sub2 …
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libtop.la
libtop_la_SOURCES =
# Dummy C++ source to cause C++ linking.
nodist_EXTRA_libtop_la_SOURCES = dummy.cxx
libtop_la_LIBADD = \
  sub1/libsub1.la \
  sub2/libsub2.la \
...
```

The secret gravy is `nodist_EXTRA_xxxx_la_SOURCES`.

More details in here: https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Libtool-Convenience-Libraries.html